# Renaming rcx.d symlinks to simulate update-rc in order to activate sshd on boot in raspberry pi

Tags: boot, ssh, sd-card, systemd

ps: I know that I just have to put a file names ssh in /boot, but that's not what I want

I have a raspberry pi running Raspbian Desktop and unfortunately it still didn't migrate everything to systemd. I'm following `raspi-config` [ssh activation script](https://github.com/asb/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config#L336) and simulating `update-rc` in my SD card by renaming the `rcX.d` symlinks from `K01ssh` to `S01ssh` in the `r2c.d, r3c.d, r4c.d, r5d.c`. However, even after this the ssh daemon won't start in boot. If, however, I type `sudo service ssh start` in the raspberry terminal, the ssh starts. Does it mean that ssh is a systemd service or that it recognized the `rcX.d` symlinks I did?

I want to make ssh start by just editing the / tree, not messing with /boot.

ps: I know it can be made through raspi-config, but I need to activate it before the SD card's first boot and I don't wanna touch the /boot partition

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. You can just enable the ssh service using raspi-config, it will be persistent throughout boots. Why do you want to do all the manual stuff?

Comment: This sounds like you want to modify the master image before burning to a card and booting for the 1st time on a new RPi. You could simply mount the partitions after burning and create the necessary `ssh` and (if needed) `wpa_supplicant.conf` files. I'm not sure why you want to use the old init script process as part of this. Is that a key part of what you want to do, or just the best solution you've encountered so far?

Comment: I don't entirely know what you mean, but see my answer below!

Comment: If sshd is your only issue have you tried to uninstall it completely then reinstall it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure why you insist on:

> make ssh start by just editing the / tree, not messing with /boot.

But, I think you don't want to create the 'SSH' file on /boot, so I get that.

Here is how I enable ssh:

```
sudo systemctl enable ssh
sudo systemctl enable ssh.socket
```

I'm not actually certain that ssh.socket must be enabled separately, that's just "works for me" kind of laziness...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to start ssh at boot?  `sudo service ssh start` won't start at boot but that allows you to start it manually. You could use a system cron? To do that use:

Make sure nano is installed

```
sudo apt-get install nano
```

Then when it's installed:

```
cd /home/pi
```

The Above is For saving file in pi directory

```
Sudo nano ssh-boot.sh
```

The above name came really be anything as your really just creating a new file just make sure it has the .sh extension!
Add the following to ssh-boot.sh:

```
sudo service ssh start
```

Save the file with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>x</kbd> and then the <kbd>key</kbd> to save the file!
Then open the cron tab to edit! The -e is for edit:

```
cd ~
```

The above is to change directory to the default one!

```
sudo crontab -e
```

If you have never used this then you may have to select an editor option! So press <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>2</kbd> As you desire! After you select, add `@reboot /home/pi/ssh-boot.sh` To the bottom of the file!

Then start the cron tab:

```
/etc/init.d/cron start
```

You can check if it's enabled with:

```
sudo crontab -i
```

The i is for info!

### I hope that helped and that I'm correct in what your issue was!